# Move Element to another div without losing events, listeners, etc (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Simply put, I'm trying to move a submenu from one location to another. (Easy) 
I need to do this without losing any event handlers, etc. (Harder)

```
  <ul id="Menu A">
      <li id="submenu">My Submenu with Clicky Events</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="Menu B">
      <!--This is where I want to move #submenu (with) all its' events intact -->
  </ul>
```

I've tried the following without success:

```
    var submenu = $('#submenu').clone(true,true);
    submenu.prependTo('.Menu B');
```

Ideally, I can find a solution without using jQuery, but if you have a solution that works with it, that would be okay.

Comment: Note: IDs ***MUST*** be unique.

Answer (score 23):

With jQuery you can use [.appendTo()](https://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

```
$('#element_to_move').appendTo('#PARENT_at_destination');
```

jQuery will cut it from its present location and move it to the new location, without losing bindings etc. *However, styles could be affected because the DOM location will change.*

This could also be helpful: https://api.jquery.com/detach/

Answer (score 15):

With JavaScript you don't have to `clone()` the node you want to move, just get a reference to it and then insert it wherever you want, for example:

```
// simple function to demonstrate a click-handling:
function spanClick (){
    // message to demonstrate that the function still works
    // without having to worry about cloning:
    console.log("So, you've clicked the span.");
    // moving the element elsewhere:
    div.appendChild(this);
}

// references to the various elements:
var span = document.getElementById('demo'),
    div = document.getElementById('recipient');

// assigning the click event-handler:
span.addEventListener('click', spanClick);
```

```js
function spanClick() {
  console.log("So, you've clicked the span.");
  div.appendChild(this);
}

var span = document.getElementById('demo'),
  div = document.getElementById('recipient');

span.addEventListener('click', spanClick);
```

```css
span {
  color: #f90;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 1em;
}
div span {
  color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<p>If you click the following <code>span</code> element, you'll log a message to the console (<kbd>F12</kbd>), and move it to inside the following <code>div</code> element. <em>It will still trigger the message</em>.</p>
<span id="demo">This is the <code>span</code></span>
<div id="recipient"></div>
```

`cloneNode()`, or `clone()`, is only required if you need to, for whatever reason, duplicate the node.

References:

- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).

Answer (score 12):

I realize this thread is super old but if anyone is here and wants to move an element WITHOUT jQuery, you can simply use `insertBefore` and this will move the element with all of its children and retain all event listeners, etc.

For example:

```
let el = document.getElementById("thingBeingMoved");
let moveTo = document.getElementById("otherThing");
moveTo.parentNode.insertBefore(el, moveTo);
```

`moveTo` is the element in the document that will be just after or next to the element being moved. If you want to move to the very end you can just get the parent container and use `appendChild`.

I am using this to reorder rows that contain many child elements including charts that are created with an external library. Even if the charts have not finished loading/rendering while I am doing the move, it does not cause any issues because the container and all of it's children that are being moved is not destroyed or altered in any way. In fact, I can still see the charts being loaded into the container as I am moving it using some pretty basic drag and drop event handlers and setting the elements position like this:

```
element.style.position = "fixed";
element.style.left= pageX + "px";
element.style.top = pageY + "px";
element.style.zIndex = 99;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it with either: 
- `cloneNode(true|false)` and `removeChild()` or
- `replaceChild()`

yet?

EDIT:
Here the example you asked for: I'll move the yahoo's menubar on the left hand side to the center. The moved menubar will have all the functionalities that it has before. (I hope that's the example you're expecting)

To make it more clear I'll use the Chrome developer tools. (the code works the same as in Firebug with Firefox)

1. Use the browser Google Chrome and go to https://de.yahoo.com/?p=us
2. [ctrl.]+[shift]+[j] in order to open developer tools.
3. [esc] in order to open the console in the dev tools.

type in the console the following things:

```
var myNode=document.querySelector("#nav-col-holder");// the element you want to move
var newNode=myNode.cloneNode(true);//it's complete clone with all the children node
var insertLocation=document.querySelector("#yui_3_8_1_1_1413153166615_364");//the location you want the clone to move to
```

Analyse where exactly you want the clone to remove to. Use `dir(insertLocation)` to get the exact target position. In this ex. I'll just put it before the 6th childNode of insertLocation

```
insertLocation.insertBefore(newNode, insertLocation.childNodes[5]);//the clone node is at the target position
myNode.parentNode.removeChild(myNode);//remove the original node
```

Now, you should see that I have just moved the menubar at the left hand side to the center of the page without loosing any functionalities of this menubar.

Hope I could help out. Bye.

Comment: No I haven't, can you mock up an example of its use?

Answer (score 0):

You are using id twice. Try this:

```
  <ul id="menua">
      <li id="submenua">My Submenu with Clicky Events</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="menub">
      <li id="submenub">My Submenu missing Clicky Events</li>
  </ul>
```

And .js:

```
$( "#submenua" ).clone().prependTo( "#submenub" );
// If you want to move instead of clone, add this line:
$("#menua #submenua").remove();
```

Comment: Forgive me. In my actual code I'm not using identical IDs. The example code above is meant to illustrate moving #submenu from MenuA to MenuB. At any one time, there is only ever going to be just one element with that #ID. :)